# Automatic installation of dependencies

Tags: ros, rosdep, manifest.xml, package, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

my package depends on the openni_kinect stack, which can be installed either from source or with apt.

I would like to write instructions for users, so that they can download and build my package and openni_kinect is automatically installed if necessary. So I added openni_kinect (I also tried with openni_camera) to my package's manifest.xml. I tried `rosdep install <pkg-name>`, which says:

```
Failed to find stack for package [openni_kinect]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [openni_kinect]:Cannot locate installation of package openni_kinect: [rospack] couldn't find package [openni_kinect]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/endres/Phd/rospacks:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
```

The same happens for openni_camera and accordingly `rosmake --rosdep-install` fails, in either case too.
Also rosdep.yaml files seem to be meant for external libraries, not ros packages.
`rosinstall` in contrast seems to be for source distributions.
Is there something I am missing, or do you have to install ros-dependencies explicitly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9740/automatic-installation-of-dependencies/) by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdeps are indeed for system dependencies (libraries), while the `<depend package=.../>` tags in the manifest are for ROS dependencies. Unfortunately, they do not automatically get resolved to Debian packages if you installed ROS through apt (though that would be nice to have).

Once your package / stack is released its stack dependencies will get mapped to dependencies on ROS Debian packages, so that if you install it all stacks it depends on will get installed as well.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3